# How do I get Value from a converted String

Tags: json, groovy

I have this code:

```
"response=3&responsetext=Duplicate transaction REFID:3154223053&authcode=&transactionid=&avsresponse=&cvvresponse=&orderid=&type=auth&response_code=300"
```

I tried converting it into json format using this code:

```
def converted = "{\"" + resp.data.toString()
                                .replaceAll('=','\":\"')
                                .replaceAll('&','\",\"') + "\"}"
```

it returns the valid json format though I want to get a specific value from that string I tried doing:

```
println converted.responsetext.toString()
```

it has an error saying

No such property: responsetext for class: java.lang.String

Comment: … You have a String. It's not some sort of magic JSON class constructed when you join the right characters together, it's just a String with JSON-format plaintext inside it.

Comment: is there anyway I could get a specific value in that json format string

Comment: Yes, see the answer section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert request parameters to Map and if required to json string as below:

```
String str = "response=3&responsetext=Duplicate transaction REFID:3154223053&authcode=&transactionid=&avsresponse=&cvvresponse=&orderid=&type=auth&response_code=300"

def map = str.tokenize(/&/).collectEntries { 
    def entity = it.tokenize(/=/)
    [ entity[0], entity[1] ]
}

assert map.responsetext == "Duplicate transaction REFID:3154223053"

// Json
println new groovy.json.JsonBuilder( map ).toPrettyString()
```

If you want to go ahead from what you have right now instead, then below implementation should be sufficient:

```
def items = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText( converted )
assert items.responsetext == "Duplicate transaction REFID:3154223053"
```